# What is failing in the communication between Angular and Spring through API?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient

I have started to create a project with Angular 11 and Spring Boot, but I am having problems with the communication via `API`. From the Tomcat server it starts from `port 8080 in the path ''`. But when creating a new record it shows me the error `POST http://localhost:4200/api/client 404 (Not Found)`.

This is my `controler.java`:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class ClienteController {
 @GetMapping({"/", ""})
    public List<Cliente> getAll() throws CMException {
        return clienteService.findAll();
    }
 @PostMapping({"/", ""})
    public Cliente create(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) throws CMException {
        return clienteService.create(cliente);
    }
}
```

This is my `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: '/api'
};
```

This is my `client.service.ts`:

```
const PREFIX = `${environment.baseUrl}/client`;

@Injectable()
export class ClientService implements IForm<Client> {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

    public list(filter: any = {}): Observable<Client[]> {
      return this.http.get<Client[]>(PREFIX, {params: filter});
    }

    public create(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
      return this.http.post<Client>(PREFIX, client);
    }
}
```

This is my `component.ts`:

```
save() {
    if (this.formNew.valid) {
      if (this.isNew) {
        this.clientService.create(this.formNew.value).subscribe(client => {
          console.log(`New client: ${cliente.id}`);
          this.back();
        }, error => {
          console.log(`Error client: ${error}`);
        });
      }
   }
}
```

I have created the `proxy.conf.json` file with the following parameters:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

**My problem**: what can go wrong so that when creating the new record the communication between the back and the front does not take place? should I add something else? I'm pretty stuck on this because I can't see the problem

Comment: @Nicholas K I have updated the question with the new file but I still have the same problem. What can I miss to complete the communication? The back if it works correctly when accessing http: // localhost: 8080 / api / client, the problem I suppose is from the front that cannot access that url, what could be the problem? Do I need to put some more information?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you hit the api from Angular?

Comment: I get the following error when trying to create a new record: ``POST http://localhost:8080/api/client net::ERR_FAILED``

Comment: The url is fine, when I directly access ``http: // localhost: 8080 / api / client`` it shows me an array with all the data. I do not know what the problem can be, I believe that everything is fine. I have configured the proxy to receive from the url ``http: // localhost: 8080``. Why is the ``URL`` wrong?. The http calls from the front are failing but I can't find the problem

Comment: If its a CORS issue then use the `@CrossOrigin` annotation. More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors).

Comment: I have already solved that problem but it still gives the POST problem when creating a new record

Comment: Can you do a console.log in the service to print out the URL before the request is actually sent?

Comment: This is the message when adding a new record: ``service: /api/client {id: "1", nombre: "nombre1", apellido: "apellido1", telefono: "123456789"}``. And when I access the url ``http://localhost:8080/api/client`` it shows ``[ ]``

Comment: But what is the url - is it right?

Comment: Yes, the URL is ``http://localhost:8080/api/client``, and accessing directly works fine but not from the front. And in the ``proxy`` I have configured the url ``http://localhost:8080``

Comment: Well, not much more we can try unless we're able to replicate it. However, try out removing the proxy entirely and just hard coding the URL in the service till the issue is resolved.

Comment: The only way it works is adding in the``controller``: ``@CrossOrigin (origins = "http: // localhost: 4200")`` and in the ``service.ts``: ``const PREFIX = `http: // localhost: 8080 / api / client`;`` But I do not want to put the fixed url in case it changes, why can this happen? Could it be a proxy problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the `baseUrl` you have to define it to your API URL which is `http://localhost:8080` as what you have currently is nothing in the `baseUrl` hence it's set to the angular url you're running on. You will have to set it in your `environment.ts` otherwise, the `PREFIX` won't point to your API

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
};
```

Set the base url in your environment ts file

Comment: I have updated the question with the new changes, the server shows the information correctly from http: // localhost: 8080 / api / client, the problem is in the front that does not communicate with the back and I do not know the reason

Comment: Are you getting a CORS exception

Comment: If I get the error ``blocked by CORS policy`` by console when I try to create a new record